# Bash - Transpose a single field keeping the rest same and repeat it across

Tags: bash

I have a file with pipe separated fields.
eg.

```
1,2,3|xyz|abc
```

I need the output in below format:

```
1|xyz|abc
2|xyz|abc
3|xyz|abc
```

I have a working code in bash:

```
while read i
do
    f1=`echo $i | cut -d'|' -f1`
    f2=`echo $i | cut -d'|' -f2-`
    echo $f1 | tr ',' '\n' | sed "s:$:|$f2:" >> output.txt
done < pipe_delimited_file.txt
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this witout using loop.
The file contains a large number of records.

Answer (score 4):

Uses a loop, but it's inside awk, so very fast:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{n = split($1, a, ","); $1=""; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {print a[i] $0}}' pipe_delimited_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Perl may be a bit faster than awk:

```
perl -F'[|]' -ane 'for $n (split /,/, $F[0]) {$F[0] = $n; print join "|", @F}' file
```

bash is very slow, but here's a quicker way to use it. This uses plain bash without calling any external programs:

```
(                                      # in a subshell:
    IFS=,                              # use comma as field separator
    set -f                             # turn off filename generation
    while IFS='|' read -r f1 rest; do  # temporarily using pipe as field separator,
                                       #   read  first field  and  rest of line
        for word in $f1; do            # iterate over comma-separated words
            echo "$word|$rest"
        done
    done
) < file
```

Comment: Thanks. With the current data volume the speed is almost similar.